# Angular2 how to integrate TIBCO spotfire

Tags: angular2-directives, spotfire

I am trying to integrate spotfire visualization in angular2. I have downloaded the spotfire api javascript ie. spotfireapi.js

I dont know how to use it in Angular2 component. I am getting error when i instantiate the following:

```
var customization = new spotfire.webPlayer.Customization();
```

Can anyone direct me the right way to use this 3rd party api in angular2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after imports of your component:

`declare var spotfire: any;`

This will fix the error you are talking about.